# Refactoring for if statements.Which is the better and which ones should change?

Tags: vue.js, coding-style, refactoring

isExample1: function () {
      return !this.isApproved && !this.currentUserIsEditor && (this.currentUserIsOwner || this.currentUserIsAdmin || this.currentUserIsArchitect)
      }

```
isExample2: function () {

if(this.isApproved) {
    return false
}

if(this.isCurrentUserEditor){
    return false
}

if(this.isCurrentUserOwner){
    return true
}

if(this.isCurrentUserAdmin){
    return true
}

if(this.isCurrentUserArchitect){
    return true
}

  return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Example 1 is not obvious. In my opinion Example 2 is better. I would recommend to use a **switch statement** that can replace multiple if checks and it is created specifically for it.

```
<script>
    var userCode = 777; // just for example

    switch (userCode) {
        case 555: // mean comparing 555 and userCode
            console.log('Nope');
            break;
        case 444:
            console.log('Nope again!');
            break;
        case 777:
            console.log('Right! (from switch 1)');
            break;
        default:
            console.log("No values have been provided that match");
    }

    var userCodeNewOne = 888; // just for example

    switch (userCodeNewOne) {
        case 800: 
            console.log('Nope');
            break;
        case 880:
            console.log('Nope again!');
            break;
        case 887 + 1:
            console.log('Right again! (from switch 2)');
            break;
        default:
            console.log("No values have been provided that match");
    }

    var user = { // kind of what you have
        isApproved: true,
        currentUserIsEditor: true,
        currentUserIsOwner: false,
    }

    switch (true) {
        case user.isApproved: 
            console.log('yes approved');
        case user.currentUserIsEditor:
            console.log('yes editor');
        case user.currentUserIsOwner:
            console.log('nope is not a owner');
            break;
        default:
            console.log("No values have been provided that match");
    }

</script>
```

A **break**  allows continuing processing in a function and just returning you out of a switch statement. You can wrap it in a function and feel free to use return keyword.

To make it clear I would use switch statement. To make it short I would create some Switch reducer like [here](https://medium.com/chrisburgin/rewriting-javascript-replacing-the-switch-statement-cfff707cf045). To make it ugly and short and bug-potential I would use Example 1.